# The “human-readable” value of the field choices in Django

Tags: django, model, choicefield

```
PAYCODE_BLUEPAY = "BLUEPAY"
PAYCODE_HEARTLAND = "HEARTLAND"
PAYCODE_1STPAY = "1STPAYMENT"
PAYCODE_CHOICES =(
    (PAYCODE_1STPAY, '1St Payment'),
    (PAYCODE_BLUEPAY, 'Bluepay Payment'),
    (PAYCODE_HEARTLAND, 'HeartLand Payment'),

)

class Payment(models.Model):
    paymentmethod = models.CharField("Payment Method", max_length=20, choices = PAYCODE_CHOICES, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paymentmethod
```

The method `__str__(self)` will return `BLUEPAY` or `HEARTLAND` or `1STPAYMENT`. But I want `__str__(self)` return **1St Payment**, **Bluepay Payment** or **HeartLand Payment**.

Please give me solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_paymentmethod_display()
```

see [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)